How to get a large file on a completely full `btrfs` partition back into a "workable" state, e.g. by truncating it?
I have a hard disk with a single btrfs partition (sdc1):
# lsblk
[...]
sdc      8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 465.8G  0 part /mnt/exthd

This partition is currently completely full:
# btrfs fi show /dev/sdc1
Label: none  uuid: 3130b777-c72d-4375-a344-43571afc3e92
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 448.74GiB
    devid    1 size 465.76GiB used 465.76GiB path /dev/sdc1

# btrfs fi df /mnt/exthd
Data, single: total=463.73GiB, used=448.22GiB
System, DUP: total=8.00MiB, used=80.00KiB
Metadata, DUP: total=1.01GiB, used=533.98MiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=498.27MiB, used=0.00B

All the partition's space is currently allocated to one single image file:
# ls -l /mnt/exthd
total 514224320
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 526676328448 Aug 16  2024 backup.img

Note: I'm using transparent zstd compression. That's why the size of the file (> 490GiB) is even larger than would theoretically fit on the disk.
backup.img is an image of a hard disk that is currently failing, created using ddrescue. Unfortunately, whatever this file contains is not complete because ddrescue stopped in the middle of its work because it ran out of space.
So I would like to let ddrescue continue working on "as much" of this partially completed image file "as possible" because I don't know how long the failing hard disk will last - so maybe what I have already successfully rescued might soon be gone for good. However, with the btrfs partition being in this full state, ddrescue always exits with a "No space left on device" error message.
I've therefore decided to process the hard disk in two parts: One part should cover as much as I have already rescued (so around 400-450 GiB of the existing backup.img) and the other part should cover the rest. (So something like ddrescue --size=400G /dev/failinghd /mnt/exthd1/part1.img and ddrescue --input-position=400G /dev/failinghd /mnt/exthd2/part2.img)
To get the file & partition back into a state that ddrescue can work with without erroring out, I decided to truncate 10-30 GiB of the end of the file. This means that I accept the risk of possibly truncating data on sectors that I could never recover, but at least I could still continue working with the most of the file as-is. So I tried running:
# truncate -s 448G backup.img 
truncate: failed to truncate 'backup.img' at 481036337152 bytes: No space left on device

And then also:
# truncate -s 400G backup.img 
truncate: failed to truncate 'backup.img' at 429496729600 bytes: No space left on device

But as you can see: I'm still getting the "No space left on device" error messages.
I've also tried balancing without success, again because of no space being left:
# btrfs balance start /mnt/exthd -dlimit=3
ERROR: error during balancing '/mnt/exthd': No space left on device


This leads me to my question: What's my best option for get ddrescue continue working with as much of the file that it was able to produce so far?
I've been thinking about the following options:

truncate-ing the file (as described above), which does not seem to work
(temporarily) adding another device to the btrfs filesystem (e.g. a USB stick), then truncate-ing the file, then removing the device from the filesystem again (in the hope that I will have truncated the image file enough to have it fit fully onto the "actual" backup hard drive again)

Are there other/better options that I should look into? How do they compare?
And before I forget: I've also found the btrfs FAQ article "Help! Btrfs claims I'm out of space, but it looks like I should have lots left!" - but it only provides guidance how to diagnose the "No space left on device" message, but no guidance on how to address it.

I don't understand. What exactly were you referring to by "working on/with the image"?

Thanks for the question. ddrescue stopped in the middle of its rescuing attempt because it ran out of space. So what I currently have is only a partially populated image file. I'd like to have ddrescue continue working on (as much of) the existing image file so that I have (at least a first part of) the failing hard disk completely backed up. Does that make sense?

Right, and I noticed that I did not explain this part in the question at all. Let me edit it.

Instead of creating "the other part" inside another filesystem (right?), create a regular file there, use losetup to associate a loop device with the file, then add the device to the btrfs. This way you will expand the filesystem in question, so it will partially live inside the other filesystem and you will be able to continue working with ddrescue in a straightforward way. Can you take it from here? Or do you need more detailed guidance?

I'm still not sure what you want tbh. It sounds like you don't have a single drive that is large enough for you to complete the rescue. Assuming you have another smaller drive that you can use to expand the btrfs, and you want to do so, then why truncate the file / balance the filesystem? Assuming you don't want to expand the btrfs, and want to just rescue the remaining part to a separate file (and maybe make use of device mapper to "join" them later), then also, why do you need to truncate? (I mean, shouldn't you be able to know its exact size by using du or so?)
